# Monte Carlo simulation for approximating delta in Matlab

Tags: matlab, montecarlo, confidence-interval

I need to code the Monte Carlo algorithm for approximating delta to Matlab and calculate confidence intervals:
[image: algorithm]

but for some reason my code doesn't work, any ideas why?

```
randn('state', 100)

%Problem and method parameters
S=10; E=9; sigma=0.1; r=0.06; T=1;
Dt=1e-3; N=T/Dt; M=2^17;h=10^(-4);

 delta = zeros(M,1);
  for i = 1:M
  Sfinal = S*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T+sigma*sqrt(T).*randn(M,1));
  S_h = (S+h)*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T+sigma*sqrt(T).*randn(M,1));
  delta(i) = exp(-r*T).*(max(Sfinal-E,0)-max(S_h-E,0))/h;
end
aM=mean(delta); 
bM=std(delta);
conf=[aM-1.96*bM/sqrt(M),aM+1.96*bM/sqrt(M)]
```

The error message is

"Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements."

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly write the `for` loop since you have already vectorized it. In other words, `Sfinal` and `S_h` are vectors of length `M`, and their `i`-th entries correspond to `S_i` and `S^h_i` in the image. Since the right hand side of the `delta` expression evaluates to a vector of length `M`, which contains all the values of delta, you should assign that vector directly to `delta`, not `delta(i)`.

One more thing: the pseudo-code in the image seems to suggest that the same random number should be used for calculating both `S_i` and `S^h_i`. This is not the case in your code, since you call `randn` separately for calculating `Sfinal` and `S_h`. I think you should generate the random samples once, save them, and then use it for both calculations.

Here's the code:

```
randn('state', 100)

%Problem and method parameters
S=10; E=9; sigma=0.1; r=0.06; T=1;
Dt=1e-3; N=T/Dt; M=2^17;h=10^(-4);

xi = randn(M,1);
Sfinal = S*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T+sigma*sqrt(T).*xi);
S_h = (S+h)*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*T+sigma*sqrt(T).*xi);
delta = exp(-r*T).*(max(Sfinal-E,0)-max(S_h-E,0))/h;

aM=mean(delta); 
bM=std(delta);
conf=[aM-1.96*bM/sqrt(M),aM+1.96*bM/sqrt(M)]
```